# Invalid URI Error when using httpclient to consume REST API

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms

I am trying to consume REST API from a xamarin forms app using the following code. however for some strange reason I am getting Invalid URI Error. I also tried using an Absolute Path in the PostAsync Method but still the error persists. Can someone guide me on this please?

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseAdd = @"http://localhost:9000";

```
    public async void GenerateAPIToken()
    {

        string tsResult = "";
        try
        {

            Token token = new Token();
            //GET TOKEN
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAdd);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage();
            msg.Content = new StringContent(@"{""username"":""admin"",""password"":""admin123""}");


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress+"token/generate.php", msg.Content);


            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                HttpContent cnt = response.Content;
                tsResult = await cnt.ReadAsStringAsync();
                token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(tsResult);
                App.apiToken = token.Document.AccessToken;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you can test with postman whether you are sending the correct request

Comment: Yes Request via postman works..that is the strangest part

Comment: this is your URI: `"http://localhost:9000"`, then you do this: `client.BaseAddress+"token/generate.php"` -- what do you think is going to happen?  Use `UriBuilder()`.. you will avoid these problems. String concatenation is a horrible idea when building paths of any kind.

Comment: try this var response = client.PostAsync(baseAdd+ "/token/generate.php", content);

            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 1):

you have already specified the BaseAddress

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAdd);
```

so you do not need to do it again here

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress+"token/generate.php", msg.Content);
```

instead, just do this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/token/generate.php", msg.Content);
```

Comment: in the code you posted you show `string baseAdd = @"http://localhost:9000";` which does NOT have a trailing "/"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Don't downvote it.

Comment: There is a typo error in what I posted, actually id does

Comment: Andy17 I have no intention to downvote anything here...i'm just searching for a concrete solution. No time to play games

Comment: @cvdev you may not have, but someone did. Based on your question in it's current state, this is the correct answer. This should be accepted. If this didn't solve your problem, then open a new question.

Comment: 1. what is the actual exception being thrown?  2. which line causes the exception?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress+"token/generate.php", msg.Content);

That line causes the exception @Jason

Comment: 'An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.'

This is the complete error